# Access MONGODB database in windos server from docker executing in WSL2

Tags: mongodb, docker, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to implement a small API in docker and i need that API writes to a database which is hosted on the same server but running on windows server 2006

I can't change the OS in the server because that server also works as a gateway for Powerbi

Should i mount the volume to  (I'm guessing  C:/mongodb/data) or should i make the insert by the localhost

These are my limitations :

```
host: running windows server 2006 (cant change this) 

app: a container running in windows subsystem for linux (it has to run on  linux because i need async functions and i only have knoweldge in python|nodejs) but it has to persist the data in the mongo database running on host

mongo database : it has to be running in windows server because a Power Bi Gateway is running comsuming data
```

keeping with diagrams maybe this will help to explain this in a better way

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your system is as in the picture. You want to write data to MongoDB. There should be a network bridge to connect between the host and the Linux environment. You can access MongoDB via bridge IP. If you want to run another MongoDB and mount disk where is in the host. It is not reliable because the data may conflict.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer , i edited mi question , and added more information about this problem , any help or advice will be really usefull